# Finding and Formatting Words in Pig

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have a file where each line of the data is in the json format, but the entire file is not. I'm using pig to mess with/format it in the form of:

```
value1a | value2a | ... 
value1b | value2b | ...
```

and so on, as well as grab a list of the column names.

I was able to mess with it and got to the form of:

```
{
column1
value1a
column2
value2a
....
}
{
.
.
.
{
...
}
```

Each row begins with `{` and ends with `}`. From there, I want to format the data as noted above.

Is it possible to do this with pig? I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Would it be simpler to try to make a separate loader that will accept the input I want? Is there an easy way to format values that are selected?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a UDF that, given a string for the schema, will parse for the key:value pairs, and then just spit everything out in the form of `(value1a, value2a, value3a...)`

From there, it was just a matter of replacing the commas with pipes.

Potentially overkill, but it gets the job done :)